# Changing colors of R plot points based on Status in Data set

Tags: r, colors, functional-programming

I have been working with a data set containing variables: Names(for solar panel array plants), Year Completed, and Status(complete, incomplete & in-progress). I have made a plot with the "Name" and "Year Completed" data points, however I want to color each data point based on its "Status"(complete, incomplete, in-progress)

I tried using this function but to no avail

```
fill_colors <- c()
for (m in 1:length (solar$Status)) {
if (solar$Status[m] == "completed") {
    fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#F2F0CE")
} else {
    fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#cccccc")
}
}
```

Here is a sample of the data set - 
`State                                                        Name Year.completed                  Status

1      CO                                             Alamosa WTF           2008               completed

2      CO                    Arvada Ralston Water Treatment Plant           2008               completed

3      CO                                      Rifle Pump Station           2008               completed

4      CO                                NREL Mesa Top PV Project           2008               completed

5      AZ                                  Pima County Wastewater           2011               completed`

Here is what the visualization looks like in its current state
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5x3upwe3tre5qh/line_plot.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxmxgxcm0oefhww/line_plot.jpg)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxmxgxcm0oefhww/line_plot.jpg

Heres my plot command to clarify:

```
plot(solar$Name, solar$Year.completed, ylim=c(1990, 2025), xlim=c(1, 213), yaxt="n", xaxt="n", col=as.factor(solar$Status))
axis(1, at=1:length(unique(solar$Name)), labels=unique(solar$Name), cex.axis=0.5, las=2)
axis(2, at=1990:2025, labels=1990:2025, cex.axis=0.5, las=2)
points(solar$Name, solar$Year.completed, ylim=c(1990, 2025), yaxt="n", xaxt="n", type="h", pch="10")
```

Comment: dropbox link is broken...

Comment: Could you add your `plot` command?

Comment: Updated the link and added my plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`plot(solar$StateName, solar$YearCompleted, col=as.factor(solar$Status))`

Comment: it ran fine, but no visual changes. Do I need to spec the colors somewhere?

Comment: Basically I want the corresponding plots to show up as green for "completed", yellow for "in-progress" and red for "incomplete"

Comment: @tijanicharles `solar$Status <- factor(solar$Status,levels=c("completed", "in-progress","incomplete"))` should give levelled factors. So for `col`- `1,2,3` corresponds to `green, yellow, red`.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the order of the factor.

```
as.factor(solar$Status)
> Levels: a b c
```

Say I want a -> green, b -> yellow, c -> red. Set the palette values with:

```
palette(value=c('green','yellow','red'))
```

It will open a plot window. Enter your plot command, and it will color each factor in the order of the palette you set (it will recycle colors if you have set fewer than the number contained in your factor levels).

```
plot(solar$StateName, solar$Year.completed, col=as.factor(solar$Status))
```

Comment: got an error message saying: Error: unexpected symbol in "Levels: approved completed"

Comment: Can you post the output of this please: as.factor(solar$Status)
I imagine that's causing the error.